# Obtain the A Prior Probability, having four random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to obtain the a prior probability of one random variable V1. I have three other random variables and their a prior probability V2, V3 and V4.

I know that if only X and Y are given , I obtain the a prior probability of X through marginalization :

**corrected version**

```
                            P(X) = P(X ∧ Y)+P(X ∧ ¬Y).
```

So applying this to my example:

```
      P(V1) = P(V1 ∧ V2)+P(V1 ∧ ¬V2)+P(V1 ∧ V3)+P(V1 ∧ ¬V3)+P(V1 ∧ V4)+P(V1 ∧ ¬V4)
```

is this correct?

In my lecture slides it is written differently:

```
         P(V1) = P(V1|V2)P(V2)+P(V1|V3)P(V3)+P(V1|V4)P(V4)
```

And I am not sure how this formula is obtained, because

```
         P(V1|V2)P(V2) equals to P(V2 ∧ V1) and not P(V1 ∧ V2)+P(V1 ∧ ¬V2)
```

I am sure I am missing something.

Comment: Please explain your notation. What does the star operator mean? For instance, what is $P(X\land Y)*(X\land\neg Y)$?

Comment: it should represent a multiplication. I have edited my post. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: How is this multiplication defined? You're multiplying a probability by an event?

Comment: Oh right. True it should be an addition here. I will correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation for the example is incorrect: 
you may write P(V1) = P(V1 ∧ V2)+P(V1 ∧ ¬V2) OR P(V1) = P(V1 ∧ V3)+P(V1 ∧ ¬V3) OR P(V1) = P(V1 ∧ V4)+P(V1 ∧ ¬V4).

Another way to think about your first equation (involving X and Y) is the following: if $A$ and $B$ are two events which are disjoint and cover the whole space (i.e. $A$ and $B$ are complementary), then we can split $P(X)$ as $P(X ∧ A)+P(X ∧ B)$. We could further write $P(X ∧ A)$ as $P(X|A)P(A)$ and similarly for $B$.

Now, what is on the slides is the same idea but instead of TWO disjoint events covering the space, you have three: $V_2,V_3,V_4$. So first $P(X)$ is split as $P(X ∧ V_2)+P(X ∧ V_3)+P(X ∧ V_4)$ and then each term is split again into a product as explained in the previous paragraph.